# silverlight not working when surrounded with iframe tag

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

I have a Silverlight Application , and i hosted it in a asp webpage..like this:

```
 <iframe width="908" height="600">
                <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2"
                    width="908" height="600">
                    <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Gsilver3.xap" />
                    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
                    <param name="background" value="transparent" />
                    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50826.0" />
                    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                    <%--<param name="windowless" value="true" />--%>

                    </a>
                </object>
            </iframe>
```

notice the iframe tag, i used this tag to get rid of the solution that my menu is disappearing behind the SL ,but my problem is when the page is opened . there is nothing is shown..jus a blank page..what should i do to let my SL works..Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The iframe tag isn't really meant to be used as an actual container element, moreso an inline frame containing contents from an outside source.

What you could do is create another page that only contains your Silverlight plugin, and then set the 'src' attribute of the iframe to the page that contains your Silverlight plugin.

```
<iframe height="908" width="600" src="NewSilverlightPage.aspx"></iframe>
```